# Turning relative numbering on (with linum-relative) in Spacemacs only when in normal mode

Tags: evil, spacemacs, linum-mode, line-numbers

In Vim I have relative numbering which is turned on most of the time but it's turned off when in **insert** mode or when the **window losses focus** (both when changing to another Vim window or when changing to another tmux window).

*How do I set this up in **Spacemacs**?*

I think my main issue is that I don't know how to make Spacemacs do certain actions only when in certain evil-modes *(I'm really new to Emacs, I've been using Vim until I discovered the wonderful Spacemacs)*.

Comment: You'll need to both enable and disable relative numbering at the right conditions for this to work. Use hooks triggering for the respective events. `evil-normal-state-entry-hook` and `evil-normal-state-exit-hook` look like good candidates for state changes, `focus-out-hook` could cover program focus, but there is no ready-made candidate for switching window focus, so I'd either play around with `window-configuration-change-hook` or advise `select-window`.